# Creating a SKPhysicsBody on a triangular sprite

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, polygon, skphysicsbody

I have a sprite that looks like this.

[image]

How would I create an SKPhysicsBody for this sprite? I want it so that the SKPhysicsBody either is a triangle or it is just an edge on the long side of the sprite. Here is what I have so far. The sprite, called rightEnemy, has an anchor point of

```
CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
rightEnemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(rightEnemy.position.x + width, rightEnemy.position.y) toPoint:CGPointMake(rightEnemy.position.x, rightEnemy.position.y + height)];
```

This creates a physics body but for some reason it is not attached to the sprite.

The sprite that the physics body is attached to is moving constantly via the update method. The y value is always changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to create the physical body from the texture.

```
rightEnemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:rightEnemy.texture size:rightEnemy.size];
```

You can also do this to validate if the physics is set correctly.

```
self.scene.view.showsPhysics = YES;
```

**Edit**

For iOS 7

Untested but I would imagine the bodyWithEdgeFromPoint: needs to be in the sprites coordinate system. You could try this which "should" draw a line from the bottom left to the top right corners of your sprite.

```
rightEnemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(-rightEnemy.size.width/2, -rightEnemy.size.height/2) toPoint:CGPointMake(rightEnemy.size.width/2, rightEnemy.size.height/3)];
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Is there an iOS 7 alternative to this??

Comment: @PoKoBros I updated my answer I think the issue was you weren't in the sprites coordinate system orgininally. You could also try bodyWithPolygonFromPath: Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Swift version of the answer.

```
    var trianglePath:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, self.size.width/2, -self.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -self.size.width/2, -self.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)

    self.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody( polygonFromPath: trianglePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a triangle shaped physics body like this:

```
CGMutablePathRef trianglePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode.size.width/2, myNode.size.height/2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, myNode.size.width/2, -myNode.size.height/2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode.size.width/2, -myNode.size.height/2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -myNode.size.width/2, myNode.size.height/2);
myNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:trianglePath];

CGPathRelease(trianglePath);
```

The above creates a 45 degree right facing triangle.